# Aerospike - bad argument (number expected, got string) in a User Defined Function

Tags: lua, aerospike

I'm trying to run a UDF to remove an item on a list present in Aerospike DB. When I execute UDF through Java, I'm getting this type error.

**Java Code**

```
client.execute( policy, key, "deletenames", "delete", Value.get(usr.getName()) );
```

**Lua UDF**

```
function delete(rec, name)
    local lii = rec['names']
    if lii then
        list.remove( lii, name )     <---- ERROR HERE
        rec['names'] = lii
        aerospike:update(rec)
    end
end
```

**Error**

```
Exception in thread "main" com.aerospike.client.AerospikeException: Error 100,1,30000,0,0,BB955892AFD8CA0 127.0.0.1 3000: /opt/aerospike/usr/udf/lua/deletenames.lua:4: bad argument #2 to 'remove' (number expected, got string)
```

Comment: `list.remove` expects `list, integer_index` as its arguments

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff ahh I see... But what if the index is not known... Is there a way to remove an element from the list by passing the element?

Comment: Looking at the Aerospike documentation it seems like you can't use default "Lua" here. [This](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/udf/api/map.html#map-remove-) could work though. Try `map.remove( lii, name )` in your code.

Comment: You should be using native data type operations, whenever possible. They run faster, scale better and have a much more robust API: https://www.aerospike.com/docs/guide/cdt-list.html  . Look at the remove-by methods.